# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type - Angular 4 with React

Tags: angular, reactjs, webpack

New to this, and there are lots of examples of this issue but we don't have a webpack.config.js file so I'm not sure how to fix it!

We're using this Angular 4 project - https://github.com/ngrx/platform

And we need to import some React modules for an existing application we want to use in this project

We're getting an error when we try and build on the ...

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   case REQUEST_GUIDE_FULFILLED:
|     return {
|       ...filterGuideData(action.guide),
|       isLoaded: true,
|     }
```

Here is full error

```
ERROR in ./showhow-admin/app/player/redux/reducers/domain/guide.js
Module parse failed: C:\workspace\showhowAdmin\platform\node_modules\source-map-loader\index.js!C:\workspace\showhowAdmin\platform\showhow-admin\app\player\redux\reducers\domain\guide.js Unexpected token (10:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   case REQUEST_GUIDE_FULFILLED:
|     return {
|       ...filterGuideData(action.guide),
|       isLoaded: true,
|     }
 @ ./showhow-admin/app/player/redux/reducers/domain/index.js 7:0-29
 @ ./showhow-admin/app/player/redux/reducers/index.js
 @ ./showhow-admin/app/player/redux/setupStore.js
 @ ./showhow-admin/app/player/redux/setupFullStore.js
 @ ./showhow-admin/app/player/redux/index.js
 @ ./showhow-admin/app/player/player.module.ts
 @ ./showhow-admin/app/guides/components/guide-detail.ts
 @ ./showhow-admin/app/guides/components/index.ts
 @ ./showhow-admin/app/guides/guides.module.ts
 @ ./showhow-admin async
 @ ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./showhow-admin/main.ts
```

Here is the package.json, not sure where to add the parts that will handle the ...

```
{
  "name": "@ngrx/platform",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "monorepo for ngrx development",
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
    "build": "ts-node ./build/index.ts",
    "deploy:builds": "ts-node ./build/deploy-build.ts",
    "test:unit": "node ./tests.js",
    "test": "nyc yarn run test:unit",
    "clean": "git clean -xdf && yarn && yarn run bootstrap",
    "cli": "ng",
    "coverage:html": "nyc report --reporter=html",
    "example:start": "yarn run build && yarn run cli -- serve",
    "example:start:aot": "yarn run build && yarn run cli -- serve --aot",
    "example:test": "jest --watch",
    "example:build:prod": "yarn build && yarn cli -- build --aot -prod --base-href \"/platform/showhow-admin/\" --output-path \"./example-dist/showhow-admin\"",
    "ci": "yarn run build && yarn run test && nyc report --reporter=text-lcov | coveralls",
    "prettier": "prettier --parser typescript --single-quote --trailing-comma es5 --write \"./**/*.ts\"",
    "watch:tests": "chokidar 'modules/**/*.ts' --initial -c 'nyc --reporter=text --reporter=html yarn run test:unit'",
    "postinstall": "opencollective postinstall",
    "changelog": "conventional-changelog -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s -r 0",
    "release": "lerna publish --skip-npm --conventional-commits && npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.5",
    "npm": ">=4.0.0",
    "yarn": ">=0.27.5 <2.0.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": [
      "yarn prettier",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ngrx",
    "angular",
    "rxjs"
  ],
  "author": "Rob Wormald <robwormald@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {},
  "nyc": {
    "extension": [
      ".ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "**/*.spec",
      "**/spec/**/*"
    ],
    "include": [
      "**/*.ts",
      "**/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngrx/db": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/glob": "^5.0.30",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^20.0.2",
    "@types/jsplumb": "file:../../jsPlumb/types/jsplumb",
    "@types/jsplumbtoolkit": "file:../../jsPlumb/types/jsplumbtoolkit",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "@types/ora": "^0.3.31",
    "@types/rimraf": "^0.0.28",
    "Aframe-Material": "https://github.com/etiennepinchon/aframe-material.git",
    "aframe": "0.6.1",
    "aframe-animation-component": "^3.2.5",
    "aframe-canvas": "0.0.6",
    "aframe-draw-component": "^1.5.0",
    "aframe-extras.grid": "^3.11.4",
    "aframe-html-shader": "^0.2.0",
    "aframe-look-at-component": "^0.6.0",
    "aframe-mouse-cursor-component": "^0.5.2",
    "aframe-react": "^4.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "chokidar": "^1.7.0",
    "chokidar-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "^2.1.1",
    "conventional-changelog": "^1.1.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "coveralls": "^2.13.0",
    "cpy-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "deep-freeze": "^0.0.1",
    "fetch-jsonp": "^1.1.3",
    "fs-extra": "^2.1.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.0.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "jest": "^21.0.2",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^3.0.1",
    "jest-zone-patch": "^0.0.7",
    "jsplumbtoolkit": "file:../../jsPlumb/jsplumbtoolkit.tgz",
    "jsplumbtoolkit-angular": "file:../../jsPlumb/jsplumbtoolkit-angular.tgz",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lerna": "^2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^4.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "module-alias": "^2.0.0",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.3",
    "nyc": "^10.1.2",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.5.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-observable": "^0.16.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "rollup": "^0.50.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "sorcery": "^0.10.0",
    "tincanjs": "^0.50.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.1.0",
    "tslib": "1.6.0",
    "tslint": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.0",
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.22",
    "url-parse": "^1.1.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "opencollective": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "collective": {
    "type": "opencollective",
    "url": "https://opencollective.com/ngrx",
    "logo": "https://opencollective.com/opencollective/logo.txt"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts",
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfigFile": "showhow-admin/tsconfig.spec.json"
      },
      "__TRANSFORM_HTML__": true
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/showhow-admin/**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "js",
      "html",
      "json"
    ],
    "mapCoverage": true,
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/modules/*.*/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@ngrx/(?!db)(.*)": "<rootDir>/modules/$1"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!@ngrx)"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "dist"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the Angular-cli.json

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "showhow-admin"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "showhow-admin",
      "outDir": "example-dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "bc",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "showhow-admin/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "showhow-admin/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {
      "inlineStyle": true,
      "inlineTemplate": true,
      "flat": true,
      "spec": false
    }
  }
}
```

Any help gratefully received, we've lost a day and half over this!

Comment: The platform seed does not use webpack - it uses rollup.  The error appears to be webpack related.  Are you trying to use webpack?

Comment: Thanks. We're not trying to use webpack or change anything. We're just trying to get it to compile with react files in there.  We haven't changed the platform at all, apart from try and introduce a React component.

Comment: Very strange. Clearly its a webpack error.. are you building with 'npm run build'?

Comment: yarn run example:start

Comment: Looking at package.json, the example is using @angular/cli to build and serve the app. So the code is use `ng` to build and bundle the app (behind the scenes, it is using webpack)

Answer (score 1):

Since the example app relies on `@angular-cli`, you can add support for `react` by importing the module from any .ts file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Make sure you install `react` as a module using `npm`:

```
npm install react --save
```

For type-safety and intelli-sense support, also install `@types/react`

```
npm install @types/react --save-dev
```

Comment: Thanks we have one of those. I've edited the question.

Comment: hm not sure what might the problem yet.  If you tried the above things, and it still doesn't work, let me know...

Comment: Thanks. It's the same problem. It's the "..." spread it can't handle.